# Swift Fetching User's Contacts Phone Numbers

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

I'm currently working with a SwiftUI project and am attempting to get the phone numbers of the User's contacts.

I've successfully gathered the contacts and can print their `givenName` as well as their `familyName`, but I have been experiencing issues trying to work with the contacts `phoneNumbers`.

Here is the core of working code used to print the `givenName`:

```
store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: {
    (contact, stopPointer) in print(contact.givenName)
})
```

Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/31615473/6642089 as an example to work off of, here is how I'm attempting to print out the contacts `phoneNumbers`:

```
store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: {
    (contact, stopPointer) in contact.
        for phone in contact.phoneNumbers {
            var label = phone.label
            if label != nil {
                label = CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>.localizedString(forLabel: label!)
            }
            print("  ", label, phone.value.stringValue)
        }
    })
```

Attempting to iterate over the contact.phoneNumbers is enough to give me the following error with a very long stacktrace:

> connection to service on pid 88497 named com.apple.contactsd: Exception caught during invocation of reply block to message 'encodedContactsAndCursorForFetchRequest:withReply:'.
>
> Ignored Exception: A property was not requested when contact was fetched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in my `CNContactFetchRequest`.

Originally, I was only asking for the contacts given name. It looked like:

```
let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey]
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
```

The answer was this add additional keys that I needed to utse within my request like so:

```
let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
```